# Geolocation iPhone 5 and iPad 3

Tags: iphone, ipad, geolocation, ios-simulator

I have a VERY strange problem. The following code works on all my browser on my computer, and in the IOS-simulator(all devices) but NOT on my own iPhone 5 or iPad 3(both running 6.0.2).

```
getLocation: function()
{   
    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {   console.log('It is supported');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);
    }

    function getPosition(position)
    {
        console.log('You should see this :/');
        var coords = [];
            coords['longitude'] = position.coords.longitude;
            coords['latitude'] = position.coords.latitude;
            console.log(coords["longitude"]);
    }
```

The following happens when I debug: In my browsers/IOS-Simulator I get all console.log messages, but in my iPhone/iPad I only get "It is supported", the next row never executes?!
What should I do?
When I try other Geolocations sites it works...really weird.

**I have put up a test site here, please tell me your results, does it work for you?**
If it works an alert popup with your longitude should show up.
[TEST SITE](http://jeho.se/mut) (Try it on your iPhone/iPad...)

Comment: It works on my iPhone 5 using Safari. In Firefox (on desktop), I also see the longitude, but then I get an error. Console: `ReferenceError: myApp is not defined myApp.fixCoordinates(coords);` at line 16.

Comment: aah, myApp is my namespace, it should not have been in the code, sorry...Weird that it works for you...what version do you have? 6.0.2?

Comment: Yes, 6.0.2. I tried it in Safari and Chrome and it works as expected in both - I see my longitude. Are your iOS preferences set correctly? Safari has access to location services and location services are turned on?

Comment: Yes they are set correctly, its really weird :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I found a solution, kind of.
When you have granted iOS Safari permission three times in a row, it will stop asking you for permission. That explains why the popup asking for my permission never appeard. When I did a restore on my iPhone (settings->restore->restore privacy) it worked.

But somehow I still think that this is a bug, my getPosition function should still execute even when I've given my permission three times in a row?

Comment: I can confirm that this is proper behavior. It does make sense - if you grant location access to a website over and over, it's nice that it stops asking after the third time. Even closing the page and/or the browser, and then reopening the webpage will not require granting location permission again. However, I would assume that after a period of time, the user would need to grant permission again.

Comment: Have you checked to see what is returned by `getCurrentPosition()`? Have you tried adding an `error` callback?

Comment: After my restore of the privacy settings the bug doesn't appear anymore. getCurrentPosition Always executes now.